# AWS API Gateway - Change http proxy status code

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I cretaed a http proxy method in my API Gateway to a remote CRM system I need to send data to.
The thing is that the CRM return all its responses as 200, and notifies for success or failure inside the response body, for example :

[image]

Hi wish to know, if there is any way inside the method to check the response using lambda function and change the status code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to modify your lambda to change the response and include an error message to model in API Gateway. [This blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/error-handling-patterns-in-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/) is a great resource for configuring these mappings.

Comment: It's not a lambda, it's a http proxy method

Comment: @MatanKadosh You asked how to check the response via a lambda function and change the status code, the blog I linked answers the second half. The first half would be dependent on what language you write your lambda in.

Comment: Hi, what i ment is that currently that method is used as a http proxy, what i needed to know if there is a way to insert the lambda function aftert that request is done

Comment: No, there is no way to have a lambda run after your integration. It would have to act as a proxy.